# Rails rake db:create error: wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 8)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I've been getting this error when I try to run `rake db:create`:

```
c:\ror\dev\AWI>rake db:create
C:/ror/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/2.4/mysql2.so: warning: constant ::TimeoutError is deprecated
wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 8)
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "port"=>3000, "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"root", "password"=>"newrootpassword", "database"=>"awi_development"}
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 8)

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Where it says I couldn't create a database I actually have 9 arguments it looks like. Why does it say I have given 7 and why does it expect 8?

I am using

```
Ruby 2.4.2 
Rails 5.1.4
MySQL 8.0.11 
OS: Windows 10
```

Comment: _you_ have 1 argument, an instance of `Hash`. The error is induced by _likely_ obsolete version of `mysql2` gem, or like.

Comment: I've got 2 mysql2 gems: `mysql2 (0.5.1 x64-mingw32, 0.4.10 x64-mingw32)`. Where do you see an instance of `Hash`?

Comment: 1. You cannot have 2 versions of the same gem simultaneously; only 1 is being used. 2. What you think are 9 parameters is in fact 1 hash instance.

Comment: If those 9 parameters are one argument, why does it say I have given 7? Where do I find the other 6 and how do I set up the 8th argument?

Comment: **The error is induced by likely obsolete version of `mysql2` gem, or like.** It’s thrown from inside the gem, check the full backtrace.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty new to this, what do you mean by check the full backtrace?

Comment: The error message says: “(See full trace by running task with --trace)”

Comment: That's just a hint that you can also get the *backtrace* if you run `rake db:create
--trace`